# MySQL Selection problem

Tags: mysql, select

I have two tables on database user and ads
when user visit the ads page I want to show him only the ads related to his country
in the ads table , there is field called contry where I insert related countries like that country="Country1;Coutry2;Country3;..." and every user have a field with his country name
How to select ads from ads table where the user's coutry is in the country field
I guess something like that

SELECT * FROM ads WHERE $usercoutry IN ads.country

Thanks for All , I found the solution

```
SELECT * FROM ads WHERE coutry LIKE '%{$usercountry}%'
```

That Code solved the problem :)

Comment: Thanks for All , I found the solution 

    SELECT * FROM ads WHERE coutry LIKE '%{$usercountry}%' 
That Code solved the problem :)

Comment: Can you mark the correct solution by checking the checkbox outline next to the answer?

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM ads WHERE country like '%$usercoutry%'
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

SELECT * FROM ads WHERE ads.country = $usercountry

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to do something like the following?

```
SELECT * FROM ads WHERE ads.country like '%' || $usercountry || '%';
```

Nota: you should use a parameter (eg a prepared statement with '?' in the query), and set the concatenated string as its value, in order to avoid SQL injection - if it's a concern.

Answer (score 0):

Need to use LIKE with the variable encased in braces:

```
SELECT * FROM ads WHERE country LIKE '%{$usercountry}%';
```